# Pivot category column having multiple corresponding value columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I have the following structure

| Company | Category | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MC | Online | 10 | 20 | 25 |
| MC | On-site | 14 | 18 | 20 |
| BK | Online | 50 | 34 | 33 |
| BK | On-site | 30 | 31 | 31 |

I want to pivot the above table so I get a single row for each of the companies:

| Company | Year1-Online | Year1-On-Site | Year2-Online | Year2-On-site | Year3-Online | Year3-On-site |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MC | 10 | 14 | 20 | 18 | 25 | 20 |
| BK | 50 | 30 | 34 | 31 | 33 | 31 |

Struggle to get it done. The names of the columns should be a concatenation of both ideally so I know which one refers to what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.set_index()`, `.stack()` followed by `.unstack()` specified levels:

```py
x = df.set_index(["Company", "Category"]).stack().unstack(level=[1, 2])
x.columns = [f"{b}-{a}" for a, b in x.columns]
print(x[sorted(x.columns)].reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  Company  Year1-On-site  Year1-Online  Year2-On-site  Year2-Online  Year3-On-site  Year3-Online
0      BK             30            50             31            34             31            33
1      MC             14            10             18            20             20            25
```